# Open Google Docs without going to docs.google.com and searching

Tags: google-drive, google-chrome

To access to my Google Docs, the regular way is go to `docs.google.com` and search by doc name. To shorten this process, I have a custom search engine in Chrome like `http://docs.google.com/#search/%s`. So I can search my doc in Chrome address bar. However, this will still go to `docs.google.com` and list all the results.

Is there any app/extension can search and open the doc right away?

Comment: How will it know which to open? Or are you looking for bookmarks to single docs?

Comment: Maybe an extension can input the doc name and open it for u.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, try the extension "Black Menu for Google"
https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/black-menu-for-google/eignhdfgaldabilaaegmdfbajngjmoke

It does what you are asking for: searching your docs and opening the doc directly.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to try out software from www.harmon.ie, which allows you to access GoogleDoc from within MS Outlook.

Answer (score 0):

Install the Google Drive desktop client and use your operating system's built-in search function. Opening the "file" in your local Google Drive folder will open your browser and go directly to the document.